# Text change on a edit box

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using an edit box as a round counter.  I would like when the text = 5 or 10 for it to show this message then it does some functions. but even when the round is 5 or 10, i never get this message  ERoundChange is the OnChange event for the ERound(edit box) ;  Any idea why its not working?  I assume i am using Self wrong?

```
{Check if round is 5 or 10}
//-----------------------------------------------------
procedure TBaseGameForm.ERoundChange(Sender: TObject);
//-----------------------------------------------------
begin
 if (self.Text = '5') or (self.Text = '10') then
   begin
      showmessage('checking stats for gryph locations on round: '+self.Text);

    end;
end;
```

Also I change the round at the beginning of each players turn like so

```
ERound.Text := inttostr(Strtoint(ERound.Text)Mod 10+1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ERoundChange` is a method of `TBaseGameForm`, `Self` refers to the current instance of `TBaseGameForm`, that is, to the *form*, and not the edit box inside it.

Hence, `Self.Text` is the caption of the form, and not the text inside the edit box. If the edit box is named `Edit1`, you should do

```
procedure TBaseGameForm.ERoundChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Edit1.Text = '5') or (Edit1.Text = '10') then
    ShowMessage('checking stats for gryph locations on round: '+ Edit1.Text);
end;
```

You could also do

```
procedure TBaseGameForm.ERoundChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ((Sender as TEdit).Text = '5') or ((Sender as TEdit).Text = '10') then
    ShowMessage('checking stats for gryph locations on round: '+ (Sender as TEdit).Text);
end;
```

since the control that caused the event is stored in the `Sender` argument. But since `Sender` is declared as `TObject`, you need to cast it to the actual `TEdit` which it is.

[You could have figured this out yourself. Indeed, the procedure  `TBaseGameForm.ERoundChange` itself has nothing to do with the edit control -- sure, it is assigned to an event of this control, but of course you can assign it to other controls as well, and use it in any other way you like. Hence, by itself, it is only associated with `TBaseGameForm`, so really, `Self` couldn't logically refer to anything else.]

Comment: ERoundChange is not a class method it is just a simple method ;o)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it!  is there an advantage to doing it between the two? if not ill take the top one as its less code :D

Comment: @GlenMorse: The obvious advantage of the last version is that you can assign it to *different* edit controls, and it will check the text in the edit control that was just changed. But if you only have one such edit control, there is no difference. In fact, the first version is safer, because then you can call `ERoundChange(AnythingYouLike)` without causing havoc. [Otherwise, you *have* to call it `ERoundChange(Edit1)`.]

Comment: I never like repetition in code, so I'd not be content with code that writes `(Sender as TEdit)` more than once. But that said, I'd also always prefer the version that keys off the `Sender` rather than building in a reference to a specific edit control.

Comment: @David: Of course you can do that. Your answer gives an explicit example of that.

Answer (score 3):

That method is an instance method of the form and so `Self.Text` refers to the text, or caption, of the form. You need to use

```
(Sender as TEdit).Text
```

instead.

Although, to avoid duplication you should use a local variable to hold the edit control reference:

```
procedure TBaseGameForm.ERoundChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Edit: TEdit;
begin
  Edit := (Sender as TEdit);
  if (Edit.Text = '5') or (Edit.Text = '10') then
    ShowMessage('checking stats for gryph locations on round: ' + Edit.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Just for the record. If you choose this approach, and if you want to call the function manually, you have to pass the correct `TEdit` control as the argument (`Sender`); you cannot do `ERoundChange(nil)`, `ERoundChange(Self)`, or something like that.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You could have said the same in your own answer.

Comment: I did, actually. (In a comment, just like here.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The `Sender` parameter often feels unsatisfactory to me. I don't like the fact that it is untyped. As for calling event handlers from code, I don't very much care for that. I'd rather write a separate method which is then called from the event handler. If you follow this policy you can assume that event handlers are always passed a meaningful `Sender`.